# Installing Emacs color theme

Tags: linux, emacs, colors, themes

I've been trying to install color themes for emacs and I'm not quite sure how I can do it. I have downloaded an `.el` file and put it under my `.emacs.d` folder, then edited my `.emacs` file and added this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/empty-void.el")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme.el")
(require 'color-theme)
(load-theme 'empty-void)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
    (color-theme-initialize)))
```

Then I opened emacs and tried to do `M-x color-theme-empty-void` but there isn't any command like that. So I did `M-x color-theme-select` but the theme was not listed there either.

I tried this with other theme files too but I couldn't get it to work. How can I load the theme files to color-theme?

Comment: In general, the `.emacs.d` root directory is not automatically included within the `load-path`.  A path to an `*.el` file is not usually used in conjunction with `load-path`, but instead is normally used in conjunction with `load-file` -- without using `add-to-list`.  So those are likely your first two problems right off the bat.

Comment: For example, you could use `(load-file "~/.emacs.d/empty-void.el")
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/color-theme.el")` and then not even worry about the `load-path`.  I've seen experienced Emacs users recommend setting up sub-directories in the `.emacs.d` folder, e.g., `~/.emacs.d/lisp` -- and you can add that sub-directory to your `load-path` and put your `*.el` files inside it and then use something like `(require '...)` assuming of course that there is a `(provide '....)` statement at the bottom of each `*.el` file that you are seeking to `require`.

Comment: Using `load-file` did the trick for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**:  Download the latest version of color-theme -- i.e., `color-theme-6.6.0.zip` from:  http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/

**Step 2**:  Extract archive to the `~/.emacs.d` directory.  This process will create the following two directories:  `~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0` and `~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0/themes`

**Step 3**:  Download (to the preferred location, e.g., `~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0/themes`) the original source of the file that is *presumably* being used by the original poster of this particular thread -- i.e., `color-theme-empty-void.el` from ( http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/color-theme-empty-void.el ).  I choose to keep the same name of the file and I saved it to:  `~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0/themes/color-theme-empty-void.el`

**Step 4**:  Add the following lines of code to the `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme-6.6.0")

(require 'color-theme)

(color-theme-initialize)

(color-theme-empty-void)
```

**Step 5**:  Restart Emacs and enjoy.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are adding to `custom-theme-load-path`, which is for Emacs **custom** themes, when the question is not about Emacs custom themes but about **color** themes, as defined by library `color-theme.el`. [Custom themes and color themes are different](http://www.emacswiki.org/ColorAndCustomThemes). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Drew -- I assumed the original poster wanted the best of both worlds -- i.e., that the O.P. wanted the ability to use the standard `color-theme` library, and that the O.P. also wanted a special theme called `empty-void` that was downloaded separately (with that `empty-void` theme loading automatically when Emacs starts).

Comment: Is the `empty-void` theme a custom theme then? If not, I still don't understand. (Not that I need to or that you need to help me understand. ;-))

Comment: @Drew -- I'm guessing based on a quick Google of `empty-void emacs theme` that the O.P. *might* be using http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/color-theme-empty-void.el  However, the file name `color-theme-empty-void.el` is *different* than `empty-void.el`.  I just downloaded `color-theme-6.6.0.zip` from http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/ and did a word search of `color-theme.el` and didn't see anything that looked like `empty-void`.  I don't know if `empty-void.el` (cited by the O.P.) was intended to be a custom theme or was instead to be used in conjunction with `color-theme`.

Comment: A google search for `empty-void.el` indicates that it is probably `color-theme-empty-void.el` that is meant.

Comment: @Drew -- Thank you -- I revised the answer with a suggested method for manual installation (without using the make utility that is included in the color-theme source package).